# Java Stored Procedure to return ARRAY

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

I have the following use case where I have a table type as OUT param to my function which invokes a java stored procedure. I am struggling to get this working. Can you plz help me in this regard ?

**SQL Record Type**

```
TYPE tmsint_xfer_html_ws_objr AS OBJECT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 (file_name           VARCHAR2(200),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  html_text           VARCHAR2(2000),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  job_id              NUMBER(10));
```

**SQL Table Type**

```
TYPE tmsint_xfer_html_ws_objt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  AS TABLE OF tmsint_xfer_html_ws_objr;
```

**Java POJO to map the SQL Record Type :**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class ExtractXmlLine implements SQLData {

    public ExtractXmlLine(String file_name, String html_text,BigDecimal job_id) {
        super();
        this.file_name = file_name;
        this.html_text = html_text;
        this.job_id = job_id;

    }

    private String sql_type;
    private String file_name;
    private String html_text;
    private BigDecimal job_id;    

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return sql_type;
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        sql_type = typeName;
        job_id = stream.readBigDecimal();
        file_name = stream.readString();
        html_text = stream.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeBigDecimal(job_id);
        stream.writeString(file_name);
        stream.writeString(html_text);
    }
}
```

**Java class that is registered as java stored procedure**

```
public class ExtractData {
    public ExtractData() {
        super();
    }

    public static void getDataFromURL(String jobId, String sourceUrl, String userName, String password,
                                                   ExtractXmlLine[] xmlResponse, String[] errorMessage) {

        try {
            conn = JDBCUtil.getConnection();
            java.util.Map map = conn.getTypeMap();
            map.put("TMSINT_XFER_HTML_WS_OBJT", Class.forName("ExtractXmlLine"));
            conn.setTypeMap(map);

            response = HttpUtil.getHttpResponse(sourceUrl, userName, password);

            if (response.getStatus().equals(ReturnStatus.SUCCESS)) {
                String xmlBody = response.getResponseBody();
                if (xmlBody != null) {
                    xmlBody = xmlBody.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");
                    xmlBody = XMLUtil.format(xmlBody);
                    textLines.addAll(Arrays.asList(xmlBody.split("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r")));
                }

                if (!textLines.isEmpty()) {
                    dataLines = new ExtractXmlLine[textLines.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < textLines.size(); i++) {
                        // ignore xml declaration lines
                        if (!textLines.get(i).startsWith("<?xml")) {
                              xmlResponse[i] = new ExtractXmlLine(sourceUrl, textLines.get(i), new BigDecimal(jobId));                            
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            } else
                errorMessage[0] = response.getErrorMessage() + response.getResponseBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMessage[0] = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
        }
    }       

}
```

**SQL Procedure to wrap the java call**

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE getDataFromURL
    (pJobID         IN VARCHAR2,
     pSourceURL     IN VARCHAR2,
     pUserName      IN VARCHAR2,
     pPassword      IN VARCHAR2,
     pXMLResponse   OUT tmsint_xfer_html_ws_objt,
     pErrorMessage  OUT VARCHAR2)
  IS LANGUAGE JAVA
     NAME 'ExtractData.getDataFromURL
             (java.lang.String,
              java.lang.String,
              java.lang.String,
              java.lang.String,
              ExtractXmlLine[],
              java.lang.String[])';
```

Is this the correct approach ? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: You haven't explained the problem you are having. What exactly are you struggling with? Do you get an error, or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Initially I wasnt implementing SQLData and rather simply constructed oracle.sql.ARRAY to map to the table type, then I received inconsistent data types issue. Later after check few forums, realised that we need to implement SQLData and changed the code to above. Now its failing inside java saying ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at                                                 **xmlResponse[i] = new ExtractXmlLine(sourceUrl, textLines.get(i), new BigDecimal(jobId));**

Comment: Well, you don't see to be initialising xmlResponse; but as you also haven't shown declaring conn, textLines or dataLines you may just have removed that from the code you posted. Or is `dataLines = new ExtractXmlLine[textLines.size()]` actually supposed to be `xmlResponse = ...`? (Incidentally, element 0 of the array will end up empty because you skip the XML declaration line but don't have a separate output line counter. That may be what you expect/want though).